# When does Chef update resources?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am not quite sure when Chef updates resources. Here is the command I ran and the response I got:

```
sudo chef-client -zr "recipe[workstation]"
[2017-10-03T14:01:26+00:00] WARN: No config file found or specified on command line, using command line options.
Starting Chef Client, version 12.14.89
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["workstation"]
[2017-10-03T14:01:28+00:00] WARN: Cookbook 'cookbooks' is empty or entirely chefignored at /home/centos/cookbooks/cookbooks
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - workstation (0.2.1)
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 7 resources
Recipe: workstation::setup
  * yum_package[vim-enhanced] action install (up to date)
  * yum_package[emacs] action install (up to date)
  * yum_package[tree] action install (up to date)
  * yum_package[git] action install (up to date)
  * yum_package[ntp] action install (up to date)
  * template[/etc/motd] action create
    - update content in file /etc/motd from c102c5 to e0c53e
    --- /etc/motd   2017-09-22 16:41:57.273701730 +0000
    +++ /etc/.chef-motd20171003-2405-1ygf6go    2017-10-03 14:01:34.211094244 +0000
    @@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
     This server is the property of Syed
       HOSTNAME: ip-172-31-35-182
       IPADRESS: 172.31.35.182
    -  CPU: 2400.046
    +  CPU: 2400.108
       MEMORY: 1014976kB
       NAME: Syed
    - restore selinux security context
  * service[ntpd] action enable (up to date)
  * service[ntpd] action start
    - start service service[ntpd]

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client finished, 2/8 resources updated in 07 seconds
```

Just to be clear I am a total newb at Chef, but it seems like whenever I run this Chef-Client command the results vary, but many times it tells me resources are updated when I don't quite know what I did to change anything. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: What does that CPU line in your template look like? Is it using a value that changes?

Answer (score 0):

This document was instrumental in me learning how Chef converges.

https://coderanger.net/two-pass/

In addition it looks like you're using a template that has a timestamp as part of its value, so that resource will always update.

As for ntpd and why it needed to be started again.. There is no Cheffy reason why it wouldn't have been already running from the last time the recipe was converged, and the service resource appropriately does nothing if nothing needs to be done. The only explanation is there was some external state change between converges; either the server restarted and ntpd isn't set up to start automatically, or some process/person stopped the service.

Because you're talking about variable responses it would be helpful to see some examples of other responses you have received. But in general you should be alarmed if you expected no state changes between converges and you're seeing resources converge.